# How to create Hive View in BigInsight Bluemix (or any other Ambari Views)

Tags: ibm-cloud, biginsights

I would like to add HiveView Instance to my Bluemix BigInsight (basic) instance.

Knowledgecenter guidelines it that take from the Ambari web interface, click the Ambari menu items, admin > Manage Ambari to open the Administration window.  (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.2.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.admin.doc/doc/create_view.html)

Well, that menu is never displayed on IBM BigInsight Bluemix instance? Then how to proceed? Is there anyway to get that menu displayed? Is it unpossible to get HiveView in IBM BigInsight bluemix instance - btw its defaut Hortonworks sandbox

Answer (score -1):

The user created with the cluster only has ambari ui read only access. It is not possible to add hive view using the cluster user. To work with hive, you can login to shell account using ssh with the same host name as ambari URL and use either hive client or beeline client.
You can use jdbc to connect and run the queries.
The connection information is available on the cluster details page from the bluemix UI on which you created the cluster.

You can use the example given in the documentation on connecting using beeline client: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/BigInsights/index-gentopic8.html#PayGo_RunningHive_commands

As suggested, I agree that the linked page can change, or the link itself may become unreachable, the link contents are described below:

Running Hive commands through the Beeline client

HiveServer2 supports a command shell that is named Beeline to work with Hive commands.

Beeline connects to HiveServer2 but does not require the installation of Hive libraries on the same machine as the client. Beeline is a thin client that also uses the Hive JDBC driver. Beeline runs queries through HiveServer2, which allows multiple concurrent client connections and supports authentication.

```
As your_username, open the Beeline client from the shell node:

@shl01 conf]$ beeline

Connect to the Hive JDBC:

beeline>!connect jdbc:hive2://<hostname>:10000/;ssl=true;

When prompted, provide a user name and password to connect to the database. Specify the user credentials that you provided when you created the cluster. After you are connected to the database, you can run Hive SQL commands.
Create a table through the Beeline client:

0: jdbc:hive2://bi-hadoop-prod-xxxx.bi.services> create table tab1(c1 int);

The value of xxxx is a unique number that is assigned to your cluster to identify the host name of your cluster's management node.
Insert records into the table:

0: jdbc:hive2://bi-hadoop-prod-xxxx.bi.services> insert into tab1 values(1);

Select records from the table:

0: jdbc:hive2://bi-hadoop-prod-xxxx.bi.services> select * from tab1;
```